# Why is this format "[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM" a 24 hour format in Excel?

Tags: excel, date-formatting, npoi

And yet this one `[$-409]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM;@` is not and shows AM/PM correctly?

I'm using NPOI to read from a Excel file and extract some useful data for my app. While I was parsing dates, I stumbled across this interesting case.

This date `16:00:00 (4 o'clock in the afternoon)` with this format `[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM` is showing as `16:00:00` in excel.

Yet a similar format, `[$-409]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM;@`, shows `04:00:00 PM`, which I believe is correct because of the `AM/PM` notation at the end of the format string.

My excel version is this one: `Microsoft® Office Excel® 2007 (12.0.6665.5003) SP3 MSO (12.0.6662.5000)`

And I'm using the latest version of NPOI (got from the source code), which interprets `[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM` as `hh:mm:ss tt` (which doesn't match the way excel shows it)

I know that `[$-XXXX]` is the locale, I don't know about `;@`.

Why, depending on the circunstances, excel is completely ignoring the `AM/PM` part?

**EDIT: It appears the `@` is a text-placeholder for `AM/PM`  it seems. Is the absence of this token forcing excel to show a 24-hour format?**

Comment: @pnuts Yeah I thought that was off, but Excel is doing this, not me =(. If I open the xml I see this exact format. [$-F400]

Comment: Oh, I believe your got it right! I know NPOI ignores the locale part of the format string (you pass the locale as a parameter), so it doesn't know when to use "system default". It just parses the "AM/PM" and assumes it's correct to use the 12-hour format. If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @pnuts commented, [this link](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=70003) indicates that Excel uses a special sequence for system default.

> "The cause is, that Excel uses an (undocumented) escape sequence for
>   "system default". This is [$-F800] for date, long system default
>   [$-F400] for time, system default".

**NPOI** completely ignores locale information, as it's passed as a parameter to the `DataFormatter`. So, instead of using the system default, it parses the **"AM/PM"** part and shows a **12-hour format**, instead of the **24-hour system default**

I've solved my problem by changing the source code of the library to suit my needs in this case.